# To populate a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle SQL for the first time and I am trying to populate a simple table with random data.

The table is created as:

```
CREATE TABLE COUNTY 
      (COUNTYID NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
COUNTYNAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
COUNTYREGION VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
COUNTYPOPULATION INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT COUNTY_PK PRIMARY KEY (COUNTYID));
```

With countyID as an autoincremented field.

I have 5 insert statements also inserted in the format of:

```
INSERT INTO COUNTY
(COUNTYNAME,COUNTYREGION,COUNTYPOPULATION)
 values('Cork','Munster', 150000);
```

Can anyone advise me on **how to use SQL to populate the table** with random data?

Comment: Downvoted because of your comments. (Btw: you should get your terminology correct: there is PL/SQL involved in what you showed us. It is plain SQL).

Answer (score 2):

The below snippet should work for you:

```
declare

v_id  number := 1 ;
v_name varchar2(20) ;
v_region varchar2(20);
v_pop number ;

begin

while (v_id < 123)

loop

v_name    := 'Cork' || v_id;
v_region  := 'Munster' || v_id;
v_pop     := v_id * 10000;

INSERT INTO COUNTY
(COUNTYID,COUNTYNAME,COUNTYREGION,COUNTYPOPULATION)
 values(v_id,v_name,v_region,v_pop);

v_id := v_id +1;


end loop;

commit;
end;
```

This will insert 122 rows of random data into yr table. To change this just change

Answer (score 1):

If you want any random data to be inserted into your table 5 times then below query will work fine.
If you want more than 5 rows of data then just replace 5 with your desired number.

```
insert into COUNTY
select level,'Cork' || level,'Munster' || v_id,150000+level from dual connect by level<=5;
```